# How to specify own logging file while using spring boot with lombok

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2, slf4j, lombok

I am aware that some logging configuration can be specified in application.properties file. But I am interested in separating logging configuration from application configuration for obvious reasons and would prefer to use own logging file. I tried `log4j2.properties`, but spring boot seems to not detect it. Below is how my code and pom.xml is. **Could someone suggest how to setup `log4j2.properties` when using with lombok.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>LoggingWithLombak</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>LoggingWithLombak</name>
    <description>Demo project for Logging With Lombak</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import lombok.extern.log4j.Log4j2;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
//@Log4j2
@SpringBootApplication
public class LoggingWithLombakApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        log.trace("some trace logging...");
        log.debug("some debug logging...");
        log.info("some info logging...");
        log.warn("some warn logging...");
        log.error("some error logging...");
        log.info("log.getClass(): " + log.getClass());

        SpringApplication.run(LoggingWithLombakApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and adding below in `log4j2.properties` has no effect.

```
logging.level.org=WARN
logging.level.com.example.demo=ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add the properties to file `application.properties` instead of `log4j2.properties`.

If you want more complex log4j2 configuration, use file `log4j2-spring.xml` or `log4j2.xml`.

- [Spring boot log level](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.log-levels)
- [Spring boot custom log configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.logging.custom-log-configuration)